# Pandas Linear math matrix calculation

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, data-science

I have some data in a pandas dataframe and I am attempting to create another dataframe that is strictly a calculated value.

The data is from a heating plant in a CSV format that I uploaded to a Github account I created. https://github.com/bbartling/Data

```
data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Python Scripts\\SetPoint_data.csv', index_col='Date', parse_dates=True)

data.info()
```

output is:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
DatetimeIndex: 69839 entries, 2017-10-01 05:00:11.205000 to 2018-01-02 05:45:14.419000
Data columns (total 3 columns):
hwr    69839 non-null float64
hws    69839 non-null float64
oat    69839 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(3)
memory usage: 2.1 M
```

B

What I am trying to do is calculate a setpoint for a boiler system and the setpoint is based off of outdoor air temperature. `data[('oat')]` The other data points are hot water return and supply temperatures. Ultimately I am trying to see how close to setpoint the boiler system is performing.

The setpoint that I want to calculate is at 10F outdoor air temperature the heating water will be 170 setpoint and at 40F outdoor air temperature the heating water will be at 130 setpoint. And its really a simple linear reset calculation but I dont know how to build another pandas dataframe.

```
X = data[('oat')]

def setpoint_calc(X):
    A = np.matrix([[10,1],[40,1]])
    B = np.matrix([[170],[130]])
    A_inverse = np.linalg.inv(A)
    X = A_inverse * B

    return X

setpoint_calc(X)
```

output is:

```
matrix([[  -1.33333333],
        [ 183.33333333]])
```

So how do I sweep over a range of x values to come up with my calculated setpoint? setpoint  = -1.33333333 * data[('oat')] + 183.33333333

I know I need to slice/index the 2d numpy array but I am not sure how.. Is the best method in a loop?

```
setpoint = pd.DataFrame()
for X in X:
    setpoint_calc.append(X)
```

I can visually put this into a scatter plot with a some lines to represent what I am trying to calculate in a seperate dataFrame... Hopefully this makes sense:

```
plt.scatter(data['oat'], data['hws'], color='grey', marker='+')

plt.plot([10,40],[170,130], color='blue', label='Reset Range')

plt.plot([40,80],[130,130], color='green', label='130F during mild weather')
plt.plot([-25,10],[170,170], color='red', label='170F during cold weather')

plt.xlabel('Outdoor Temp')
plt.ylabel('Hot Water Temp')
plt.title('Calculated Setpoint')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image: scatter]

Comment: A couple of questions. 1. You haven't used the value of parameter X in the ``setpoint_calc`` function. Is this what you intended to do ? 2. Is the result of ``setpoint_calc`` to be used for plotting ? An example, would help.

Comment: Im trying to build a seperate pandas data frame that is a calculated value, no plotting

Comment: The use of parameter ``X`` in ``setpoint_calc`` is not clear. The current function seems to be setting the value of X without using the value that is passed in to the function. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, I think this is what you are looking for:

```
data['setpoint'] = data['oat'].apply(lambda x: -1.33333333 * x + 183.33333333)
```

This will perform the calculation on each value in the `oat` column and store the calculated values in a new column called `setpoint` on the DataFrame.

Comment: Can you tell me a little bit about the `.apply(lambda x)`? Ill have to keep learning :)

Comment: There are 2 pieces to it. The ``.apply`` allows you to apply a function that accepts a scalar value to each element in the Series. The ``lambda`` is the Python equivalent of an ``anonymous`` function.